# Recursive query with time difference

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

This is my first post here even though I am a daily reader. :)

I need to produce an MS SQL Server 2014 report that shows the clients that come back to do business with me in less than or equal to 3 days. I tried with INNER JOINS but I wasn't successful.

The way I thought of the solution is using the below Logic:

```
If product is same
    and if userId is same
    and if action was donedeal but now is new
    and if date diff <= 3 days
    and if type is NOT same
then show results
```

e.g of my Data:

```
id  orderId userId  type    product date        action
1   1001    654     ordered apple   01/05/2016  new
2   1002    889     ordered peach   01/05/2016  new
3   1001    654     paid    apple   01/05/2016  donedeal
4   1002    889     paid    peach   03/05/2016  donedeal
5   1003    654     ordered apple   03/05/2016  new
6   1004    889     ordered peach   04/05/2016  new
7   1005    122     ordered apple   04/05/2016  new
8   1006    978     ordered peach   04/05/2016  new
9   1005    122     paid    apple   04/05/2016  donedeal
10  1007    122     ordered apple   10/05/2016  new
```

Desired results:

```
id  orderId userId  type    product date        Diff
3   1001    654     paid    apple   01/05/2016  2 days
4   1002    889     paid    peach   03/05/2016  1 day
5   1003    654     ordered apple   03/05/2016  2 days
6   1004    889     ordered peach   04/05/2016  1 day
```

Could you please direct me to the functions that can be useful for me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

#

Update

Gordon Linoff gave me the suggested code below but since the Type had to be different I replicated the code and run it as per below and it worked:

select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'donedeal' and type='paid' then date end) over
                 (partition by user, product order by date) as last_donedealdate
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'new' and type='ordered' date < dateadd(day, 3, last_donedealdate)

UNION ALL

select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'donedeal' and type='ordered' then date end) over
                 (partition by user, product order by date) as last_donedealdate
 from t
 ) t
where action = 'new' and type='paid' date < dateadd(day, 3, last_donedealdate)

Comment: Self inner join is one way to go. What did you try? (Otherwise you could try a GROUP BY.)

Comment: @jarlh Would the inner join help as each row needs to be compared with each other row(s) and the ones that match the criteria (type,datediff,action)?
I tried the GroupBy and compared the MIN(date) and MAX(date) but that means that it will only compare between 2 results. There are cases where there are more than 1 match with each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.  To get the last done deal date, use `max()` with `partition by` and `order by`.  The rest is just `where` clause logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when action = 'donedeal' then date end) over
                 (partition by user, product order by date) as last_donedealdate
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'new' and date < dateadd(day, 3, last_donedealdate);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond to my post, much appreciated. One thing I left behind is that the type must not be the same. It might not be clear in my example why is important but in the real life problem it is. I have tried modifying your solution but the results were not the desired. May I kindly ask for further help with this? :)

Comment: @ct14 . . . That makes it more complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much. With a minor change I made it to work. The type is a boolean field (0 or 1). So there is only 2 scenarios for me and I replicated the code and using UNION ALL joined the 2 scenarios' results. Does it count as bad practise code?

Comment: @ct14 . . . The limit to two values helps.